# Error while connecting to local Ganache instance with Web3.js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I have a web app running on a local Node.js server (port 3000) and a Ganache instance running on port 7545. Whenever I try to connect to the Ganache instance with Web3.js I get a CORS error from the browser.

```
Node.js - v8.11.3
Ganache - v1.2.3
Web3 - web3.min.js (v0.20.7)
OS - Windows 10
```

I've tried installing the Chrome extension that disables CORS but to no avail.

This is the code I use for creating and connecting the Web3 object:

```
    var web3;
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
    }
```

This is the error message I get from Chrome whenever I click on a button that executes the connection between Web3 and Ganache:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7545/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
inpage.js:1 Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:7545.
    at Object.InvalidConnection (inpage.js:1)
    at o.send (inpage.js:1)
    at a.send (inpage.js:1)
    at w.accounts (inpage.js:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:250)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
InvalidConnection @ inpage.js:1
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:3000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you upload your project to GitHub so I can assist you better?

Answer (score 0):

in package.json file add proxy of node.js server

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I keep getting the same error

Comment: if you are running nodejs with express server setup then you can use package cors to handle this error.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using express-cors now and now it's working fine

Comment: cors is great library which handle cors related issues with express framework